# Ability to hide deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, stack-overflow-for-teams

As admin of SO Team, I see all deleted answers on the question page.

They disturb me - oftenly they appear above not deleted answers, and when I use search with Ctrl-F, it walks through all deleted answers, hindering me to find useful information.

Could please an option/setting be added: hide all deleted answers from view?

Comment: It also happens when you get to 10k on the main site. I think that the idea is that deleted content may need moderation anyway (behaviour problems, undeletion, etc). But maybe it's not exactly the same on Teams, and a "harder" delete is needed as well.

Comment: Either that, or a sorted view at the very minimum

Comment: If you sort by votes, it should put the deleted answers at the bottom. Granted, I can't check that, as I'm not an admin on a team, but that's how it works on SO main

Comment: My userscript [Sticky Post Headers & Question Table of Contents](https://stackapps.com/questions/7994/sticky-post-headers-question-table-of-contents) has an option to hide all deleted answers (preference is saved locally).